# Obtaining RADIUS attributes without authenticating

Tags: radius-protocol

My application is using a RADIUS client implementation in order to authenticate users (using username/password and a shared secret). In the response from the server (Access-Accept), various attributes are provided, and I use them for getting a few relevant user properties.

The problem: once in a while, I need to refresh the value of the "Class" attribute. I don't have the full credentials any more, only the user name, and I don't want to force the users to re-authenticate. Is there any way to fetch this attribute without the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class attribute is a session cookie which is returned by the RADIUS server in the authentication packets and then sent back by the RADIUS client in the accounting packets.
I am pretty sure you cant refresh the Class attributes without re-authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of the class attribute for an established session you may be able to issue a CoA request (dependent on NAS support).

Comment: Thanks. However, what I wanted to do is to retrieve again the class attribute, not to change anything in the session itself. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like CoA request cannot help with this...

Comment: You can turn on acct-update-interval (or whatever it's called on your NAS) and you'll receive it in Interim-Update packets which should contain it. Some NAS will also send Accounting-Requests when receiving a CoA-Request which changes any of the attribute values.

In terms of querying the NAS directly to find the Class attribute value, no, that's not possible via RADIUS, though it may be via SNMP. Check the documentation provided by the vendor.